# Groovy error: "cannot assign value of type byte[] to variable of type byte[]"

Tags: groovy

I have code that iterates over timestamps in a video, and adds the timestamp and the thumbnail of that timestamp to a list:

```
timeStamps.each { timeStampMs -> //for each carousel timestamp
     Optional<byte[]> thumbnail = this.persistenceService.getThumbnail(collectionName, mediaId, timeStampMs)
     if (thumbnail.isPresent()) {
         timeThumbnailList << new TimeThumbnailPair(timeStampMs: timeStampMs, thumbnail: thumbnail.get())
     } else {
         absentTimeStamps << timeStampMs //assign to thumbnails that needs to be decoded
     }
}
```

TimeThumbnailPair looks like this:

```
@Canonical
class TimeThumbnailPair {

    Long timeStampMs

    byte[] thumbnail
}
```

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

> "Error:(83, 103) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot assign value
>   of type byte[] to variable of type byte[]"

I'm completely lost as to why this error appears (and what it even means).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the `CompileStatic` annotation on this class (or method)? If so, does this work if its turned off? Also what version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: @cjstehno
Thank you, this solved my issue. If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add or remove a `@CompileStatic` on the class or method. Sometimes primitive arrays can be picky.